# Resume play music, after AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudioplayer

My application has the ability to call. Sound used to call AVAudioPlayer. The problem is that after a call to my application, if the music played in the background (for example, in the application "Music"), it does not restore music to play.

Tried some of the methods in this forum, but unfortunately nothing has helped. Help please, how can I solve this problem? Sorry for my english.

Comment: Does the music is been played from your own application? What exactly you want is you want to pause the music played by (iTunes for example) and start the music of your application?

Comment: For example. I listen to music in the background. Start my application, and I do call. At this time, the music that I listened to in the background have stopped. After I call, and then I finish the conversation. But the music from the background does not continue to play. I need, when I finished talking, music from the background, which stopped during the conversation, continued to play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem for myself. I check the music is playing or not, if yes then stop the music and put the flag.

```
thirdPartyPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
[thirdPartyPlayer stop];
if (thirdPartyPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStateInterrupted || thirdPartyPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying)
{
    isThirdPartyPlayerPlay = true;
}
```

Then when the call ends, I restore play back music, if there is a flag.

```
 if (isThirdPartyPlayerPlay)
{
    [thirdPartyPlayer play];
    isThirdPartyPlayerPlay = NO;
}
```

Comment: hey, I'm having the same problem. Do you know if doing this is the right approach or if the operating system should automatically continue the playback?